# is there any significant difference in these 3 different applications of php

Tags: php

I am trying to improve on my programming theory and in a previous question it was pointed out to me that I should not use multi-line ehcos in my programming as show in the first example. I use this because once it is complied it automatically minimizes the out put html. Which of the there examples below is the best practice for making use of php and why?

**1)**

```
echo '<div class="row cf">';    
echo '<div class="col_8 cf alpha">'.$page_title.'</div>';   
echo '<div class="col_4 cf omega right">';
echo '<a href="'.$table_url.'-action.php?action=add" class="button blue">';
echo '<i class="icon-plus-sign"> </i>  Add a Site</a>';
echo '</div>';  
echo '</div><hr>';
```

**2)**

```
echo '
<div class="row cf">
<div class="col_8 cf alpha">'.$page_title.'</div>
<div class="col_4 cf omega right">
<a href="'.$table_url.'-action.php?action=add" class="button blue">
<i class="icon-plus-sign"> </i>  Add a Site</a>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
';
```

**3)**

```
<div class="row cf">
<div class="col_8 cf alpha"><?php echo $page_title; ?></div>
<div class="col_4 cf omega right">
<a href="<?php echo $table_url; ?>-action.php?action=add" class="button blue">
<i class="icon-plus-sign"> </i>  Add a Site</a>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Thanks.... Pete

Comment: This is pretty much a preference question, although I think PHP was meant to be worked with as the 3rd solution; simply because it's a templating language - it's the HTML that's meant to ***encase*** the PHP, not the other way round. Secondly, it's really difficult to read the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is significant difference. The first one is especially hard to maintain. The second is a bit better, but still inconvenient.

The third one allows you to write plain HTML without the need of escaping anything. You only briefly open PHP tags to insert variables. This HTML is also property syntax-highlighted if you got a smart editor like Netbeans or even Notepad++.

So I would choose the third one, except maybe when I insert a very tiny piece of HTML.

If I may suggest a small improvement:

```
 <?php echo $x; ?>
```

can also be written as

```
 <?= $x ?>
```

In case of performance, I think there won't be much difference. I would guess that the third one is faster, since it needs to parse and execute smaller pieces of PHP. In the other ones the strings need to be parsed as well to check for special characters.

That said, I doubt if you would be able to measure any difference at all, and it shouldn't be your concern. Choose the one you like best. For optimization, you'd better find real bottle necks, which are ususally found in the area of executing too many, too complex, or poorly optimized database queries.

Comment: Note that while [short_open_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) syntax (`<?= $var ?>`) has been default enabled (it always works) since `5.4` it might not be enabled on your host. That said, it is enabled on most hosts.

Comment: The short open-and-echo tags (`<?=`) is *always* available since PHP 5.4, since it is not affected by that setting anymore. But you're right, in earlier versions you need to make sure this is available. Especially important to take that into account when you want to write reusable library code. I've never seen a host where it isn't available, though.

Comment: Hence "*has been default enabled (**it always works**)*". My explanation might've been confusing - sorry about that. :-) That said, I agree with you - all hosts I've ever used has had it enabled (and hosts that use anything less than PHP 5.4 should really consider upgrading)

Comment: So if i am understanding correctly... there really is no difference performance wise in compilation and it is mostly a preference choice of the programmer?

Comment: I don't dare to say '*really no difference at all*', but there is no *significant* difference and it shouldn't concern you.

Comment: Thanks to all... by biggest concern was between 1 and 2 with 1 being my personal preference because it automatically minimizes the output.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer solution 3 for two reasons:

My IDE (notepad++) will actually syntax highlight the HTML **and** the PHP and not just colour it the "string colour". I also do not have to escape `'`'s in the HTML by changing it to `\'` every time I use it.

Comment: thank for your input... the question was more orientated to  performance in compilation on the server side.

Comment: @petebolduc This will **never** be your bottleneck. We're talking micro-seconds difference and it will **not** be noticeable. That said the HTML outside PHP tags should always be faster (and better) as the PHP compiler doesn't need to receive the "echo" calls (or the string concatenation).

Comment: Thanks... the irony of it is that i have programmed so long according to the first example that when i look at html in my editor with the syntax highlighting i find it harder to read.